# Make a combo box list item open a webpage?

Tags: c#, html, windows-forms-designer, controlbox

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Asus";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.asus.com");
```

This is basically what I am trying to do, but it seems so hard to find some good combo box tutorials!  I am doing this with a windows form (not WPF).  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? navigating to a web page when the user selects an item in the combobox? What is wrong with the current code?

Comment: Isn't `Process.Start("http://www.asus.com");` opening the website? It should.

Comment: You should end your if statement with `)`, not `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix the syntax error

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Asus")
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.asus.com");
```

Comment: To think it was because I just missed a ")".  I was so close.  Thank you

Comment: Glad to have been of help